# Street sign on the same pole: "Pay to park" and "No Stop". Which one applies before the pole, and which one applies after the pole?

Tags: united-states, driving, washington, parking

I saw two street signs on the same pole, one is "Pay to park" and the other one is "No Stops": which one applies before the sign, and which one applies after the sign? Location: Seattle, Washington, United States.

[image]

Cars were parked before and after these street signs but it was a Friday evening so people may have been paying less attention to the parking regulations, so I couldn't guess based on the parking style of the locals.

Answer (score 1):

One can't really tell from this picture, but given the different angles at which the signs are placed, I would **guess** that "no stopping" applies to the right of the signpost as one faces the curb from the street, and "pay to park" applies to the left.

Comment: Thanks, what is missing in the picture for the assessment?

Comment: A picture of the lack of another Pay to Park sign downhill from the No Stops sign, and distance between the two signs. Also a clear determination that the No Stops sign is set in the sidewalk, to rule out the possibility that it is an illegal no-parking sign (a frequent occurrence in Seattle).

Comment: @user6726 thanks, there's no Pay to Park sign downhill from the No Stops sign. The No Stops sign is set in the sidewalk.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, check the curb.  "No stops" is usually paired with yellow or red paint.

Comment: @Mark thanks, is it possible to guess where the signs apply without looking at the painting? (since sometimes painting is missing or hard to see as many roads are  not properly maintained)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the row of stops signs are put there after the pay sign so these are the one in force. look at the different types of poles and the smaller signs with cones along the street. Could be a temporary road closure thing for doing some road works.

Comment: Thanks let's ignore the temporary no parking signs (their validity had expired despite being still present)